# vim-pandoc-syntax italic text is displayed with white background

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using the [vim-pandoc-snytax](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax) plugin to syntax-highlight pandoc-flavoured markdown. If I mark text as italic like this `*italic*`, it is displayed with a white background:

[image]

All the rest of the syntax highlighting works fine, just this white background of italic text is very disturbing.

I'm using Vim 8.0 installed from Homebrew on Mac 10.11.1. I observe the same behaviour in **Terminal.app** and **iTerm**. Currently, I use the built-in *slate* colour scheme, but this white background **appears in any colour scheme I use**.

Moreover, this white background appears whenever I set the filetype to one of `:setf markdown`, `:setf markdown.pandoc`, and `:setf pandoc`. That is, this white background appears also without the vim-pandoc-syntax plugin, if I just activate the built-in markdown syntax highlighting.

How can this white background of italic text be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that vim tried to format the text enclosed in `*` as italic, but the terminal, in which vim was running, didn't support italic text.

The Mac Terminal app doesn't support italic text at all. In iTerm, italic text can be enabled in *Preferences > Profiles > Text*.

After enabling italic text in iTerm, the white background didn't appear anymore, and instead the text was correctly displayed in italics.